# get the string output of a python function with argument input in shell script

Tags: python, shell

I am writing a function in python which gets an argument as input in shell and I want to use the output of the function in shell but I don't know how to get the output as a variable in shell.

here is my python code which outputs the dicmension of an image in string type.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pathlib import Path
import sys, os, glob
import SimpleITK as sitk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sys
#print ('Argumen List:', sys.argv[1])
#code=sys.argv[1]

def gg(code):
    sample_nii='/test/'+code+'/img_'+code+'_0000.nii.gz'

    #sample_nii=str(sys.argv)[2]
    temp = sitk.ReadImage(sample_nii)
    img = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(temp)
    print(img.shape)
    s0=str(img.shape[0])+' '
    s1=str(img.shape[1])+' '
    s2=str(img.shape[2])
    stridev=s0+s1+s2
    print(stridev)
    return stridev
```

here is the shell and I need to get the stridev in shell to use it in another command in shell. However, now when I echo stridev1 I get empty output.

```
CASES=(0029)

input_path=/nn/

for((k=0;k<1;k++))
do
python3 pp.py ${CASES[i]}
stridev1= $(python3 pp.py ${CASES[i]} 2>&1 >/dev/null)

echo "hello"
echo $stridev1
echo  ${CASES[i]}
```

Comment: There was no output to be captured in `stridev1`, because you redirected Python's output to /dev/null.

Comment: how should I make it correct?@jasonharper

Answer (score 0):

probably the problem is that you are writing the output of your Python in the `null` file in the `dev` directory. You should write the output in `stridev1`.

Your code should look like this:

```
CASES=(0029)

input_path=/nn/

for((k=0;k<1;k++))
do
python3 pp.py ${CASES[i]}
$(python3 pp.py ${CASES[i]} 2>&1 > stridev1)

echo "hello"
echo $stridev1
echo  ${CASES[i]}
```